# Avoid $var to be interpreted as a variable inside inverted commas

Tags: bash

I have tried in many ways but couldn't get it the right way.

```
fun="
mkcdo ()
{
    mkdir -p -- \"'$1'\" && cd -P -- \"'$1'\"
}"

echo "$fun" >> ~/.bashrc
```

What I want is to append this in `.bashrc`

```
mkcd ()
{
    mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
}
```

Could that be done? Is there a way in bash like there is in python: `r'whatever\you\$write'` so that it is completely ignored as simple text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative1: just use single quotes.

```
fun='
mkcdo ()
{
    mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
}'

echo "$fun" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternative2: escape the `$` sign.

```
fun="
mkcdo ()
{
    mkdir -p -- \"\$1\" && cd -P -- \"\$1\"
}"

echo "$fun" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a variable to store a `bash` function code sounds much of anti-pattern. For multi-line formatted strings, I would recommend using here-doc and quote them to avoid expanding the variable,

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'
mkcd () {
    mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
}
EOF
```

Further reading - [Bash - Here documents](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_documents)